# ¿Existe una mejor manera para filtrar resultados con PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Basicamente estoy empezando con PHP haciendo un pequeño buscador web con una base de datos que tiene algunos productos.

Mi duda viene, ***bueno quiero lograr que el usuario ponga cualquiera palabra me arroje todos los resultados que esten relacionados con lo ingresado***, yo lo hice de esta manera:

```
$registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE 
                                          idProducto LIKE '%$keywords%' OR
                                          Nombre LIKE '%$keywords%' OR 
                                          Marca LIKE '%$keywords%' ");
```

No se si hay alguna manera mas eficiente de lograrlo, ***me refiero a que si es necesario poner que se parezca a lo ingresado con cada dato de mi DB.*** 
Busque por internet pero no encuentro una respuesta clara que me saque la duda.

```
<table> 
            <tr>
                <th>ID del producto</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Marca</th>
            </tr>
```

```
if( isset( $_GET["keywords"] ) ){
    $keywords = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_GET["keywords"])));

} 
if( empty($_GET["keywords"]) ){
    echo "<p>Tenes que ingresar un criterio de busqueda</p>";
} else{
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "busqueda") or die("Could not connect");
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, "busqueda") or die("Todo mal");
    $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE 
                                          idProducto LIKE '%$keywords%' OR
                                          Nombre LIKE '%$keywords%' OR 
                                          Marca LIKE '%$keywords%' ");
    $cantidad = mysqli_num_rows($registros); 
    echo "<p>Se encontraron $cantidad resultado con la palabra $keywords</p>";
    while( $dato = mysqli_fetch_assoc($registros) ){
?>  
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $dato["idProducto"]; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $dato["Nombre"]; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $dato["Marca"]; ?></th>
            </tr>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Una forma de hacerlo, entre otras, sería esta: `SELECT * FROM productos WHERE CONCAT(idProducto, '', Nombre, '', Marca) LIKE '%keywords%'`. En cuanto al código PHP considera usar consultas preparadas para evitar riesgos de inyección SQL que podrían traer consecuencias catastróficas en tu aplicación y hasta en tu sistema operativo.

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo que no puedes preparar una consulta usando la sintaxis `LIKE '%?%'` sino que sería `LIKE ?` donde defines el parámetro ? como `"%{$keyword}%"`. ¿Estoy bien? No me suena tan seguro...

Comment: @amenadiel es como dices en caso de consultas preparadas, usas el marcador `?` y pasas el parámetro como `'%keyword%'` o bien `'%{keyword}%'`. No hay ahí ningún riesgo de seguridad.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes crear un buscador con PHP, MySQL y Ajax, para asi realizar filtros o busquedas eficientes.

Ejemplo: https://mimentevuela.wordpress.com/2015/08/09/busqueda-instantanea-con-ajax-php-y-mysql/

O si quieres puedes utilizar [DataTable](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap) o [FooTable](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/) con Bootstrap o cualquiera de otro framework CSS, que ayudan mucho y son fáciles de implementar (por detrás utilizan JS, AJAX, entre otros), solamente tienes que leer bien la documentación.

Comment: revisa por favor [answer] las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad, pues la página asociada puede dejar de funcionar, además esto parece mas una recomendación que respuesta